# Problems with Sublime text system build and cygwin

Tags: c++, json, build, system

I downloaded the 64 version for windows of sublime text, but whenever I try to compile a C++ file using the system build I get the following message:

"The program or feature "\??\C:\Users\Windows\system.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available."

For the build system I used this->

```
{
"cmd" : ["C:\\cygwin\\bin\\g++ $file -o ${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.cpp", 
"shell" : true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

I've already modify the PATH system variable...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

"cmd" : ["C:\cygwin\bin\g++ $file -o ${file_base_name}"]

I think you can append **".exe"** after "g++".